# How to remove the â\xa0 from list of strings in python

Tags: python-3.x

I have tried with the replace in python. But it wouldn't work.

```
my_list=[['the',
 'production',
 'business',
 'environmentâ\xa0evaluating',
 'the'],
 ['impact',
 'of',
 'the',
 'environmental',
 'influences',
 'such'],
 ['as',
 'political',
 'economic',
 'technological',
 'sociodemographicâ\xa0']]
```

`my_list.replace(u'\xa0', ' ')` and

```
my_list[0].replace(u'\xa0', ' ')
```

For this got the attribute error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'replace'`  How to remove this unwanted string from the list my_list?

Comment: Your title says something else than what you post your question. Do you want just `\xa0` removed, or *either* `â` or `\xa0`, or *exactly* the text `'â\xa0'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `unicodedata` library. That way you can save more information from each word.

```
import unicodedata
final_list = [[unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", word) for word in ls] for ls in my_list]
```

To also replace `â` with a

```
very_final_list = [[word.encode('ascii', 'ignore') for word in ls] for ls in final_list]
```

If you want to completely remove `â` then you can

```
very_final_list = [[word.replace('â', '') for word in ls] for ls in final_list]
```

and to remove `b'` in front of every string, decode it back to `utf-8`

So putting everything together,

```
import unicodedata
final_list = [[unicodedata.normalize("NFKD", word) for word in ls] for ls in my_list]
very_final_list = [[word.encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode('utf-8') for word in ls] for ls in final_list]
#very_final_list = [[word.replace('â', '') for word in ls] for ls in final_list]
```

And here is the final result:

```
[['the', 'production', 'business', 'environmenta evaluating', 'the'], ['impact', 'of', 'the', 'environmental', 'influences', 'such'], ['as', 'political', 'economic', 'technological', 'sociodemographica ']]
```

If you switch the `very_final_list` statements, then this is the output

```
[['the', 'production', 'business', 'environment evaluating', 'the'], ['impact', 'of', 'the', 'environmental', 'influences', 'such'], ['as', 'political', 'economic', 'technological', 'sociodemographic ']]
```

Comment: :package unicodedata works for me. After removing null spaces and special symbols still some words appears like 'environmentâ evaluating', 'sociodemographicâ'. Why? –

Comment: @9113303 Here, I've fixed almost every issue it had previously. Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 2):

```
lst = []
for l in my_list:
    lst.append([s.replace(u'\xa0','') for s in l])
```

Output:

```
[['the', 'production', 'business', 'environmentâevaluating', 'the'],
 ['impact', 'of', 'the', 'environmental', 'influences', 'such'],
 ['as', 'political', 'economic', 'technological', 'sociodemographicâ']]
```

Emmmm,The another answer,I think it break the structure of `my_list`.But it's easy too.Only one line.

Comment: Ok,My fault.I will changed it.

Comment: Better, thanks :) Your answer is what OP should be looking for, except that there is some ambiguity in the question. Leaving this as a reminder to check back later.

Answer (score 1):

Updated :
List of List Comprehension should make this work for you

```
[[w.replace("â\xa0", " ") for w in words] for words in my_list]
```

Output

```
[['the', 'production', 'business', 'environment evaluating', 'the'],
['impact', 'of', 'the', 'environmental', 'influences', 'such'],
['as', 'political', 'economic', 'technological', 'sociodemographic ']]
```

Comment: I do not think he wants triple nested lists

Comment: Updated the answer. Added the triple by mistake.

Comment: @AshokKS Your output for some reason still has the special characters. Guess it was a typo ?

Comment: @VineethSai Corrected it now. Sorry. Please up vote if you found it useful.